# UIView & Graphics Context

Tags: iphone, uiview, graphics

The UIView class does not set a graphics context, so when I go to get the current context, it comes back as nil.  I'm in a method subclassed off of UIView, how may I get the graphics context to be able to simply draw a line?  Very new at the x-code game.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graphics context is only set in the drawRect: method which you will need to override, then do all your drawing in there. As a word of caution do not call drawRect: directly, it will be called automatically when the UIView needs to be displayed. If you want to force a draw send a setNeedsDisplay message to your UIView.

Answer (score 4):

Override the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method in your UIView subclass

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDGJHF

According to the docs:

> You can get a reference to the
>   graphics context using the
>   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext function,
>   but do not retain the graphics context
>   because it can change between calls to
>   the drawRect: method.

It sets it up for you before invoking that method.